# How to set return type of a function to mutableListOf in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I made a function which returns all factors of an integer. But the problem is that it gives an error that the return type is `Unit` instead of `mutableListOf`. my code:

```
fun get_factors(num: Int) {
    var factors = mutableListOf<Int>()
    for (x in 1..num) {
        if (x % num == 0) {
            factors.add(x)
        }
    }
    return factors
}

fun main() {
    print(get_factors(18))
}
```

I tried doing:

```
fun get_factors(num: Int): mustableListOf {
    var factors = mutableListOf<Int>()
    for (x in 1..num) {
        if (x % num == 0) {
            factors.add(x)
        }
    }
    return factors
}

fun main() {
    print(get_factors(18))
}
```

but it says `mutableListOf` not defined.
I just started learning Kotlin today so I am a total beginner with Kotlin. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have confused the *type* [`MutableList<Int>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/), with the *function* [`mutableListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html).

Since the type name is `MutableList<Int>`, you should do:

```
fun get_factors(num: Int) : MutableList<Int> {
    ...
}
```

Or, if the caller doesn't need to modify the list, you can just return `List<Int>` too:

```
fun get_factors(num: Int) : List<Int> {
    ...
}
```

I can see why this is confusing - to create an instance of a type, you normally just add `()` to the end of the type name, so if `mutableListOf()` creates a list, you'd think that `mutableListOf` is the type name. However, this is actually calling the global function called `mutableListOf`, which returns an instance of `MutableList<T>`.

One way to distinguish between these is to look at the first letter. Type names usually begin with a capital letter, whereas function names begin with a small letter.